# How to store SSL / TLS certificates in a private store

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp, x509certificate

We have a c# app which comunicates with devices. By now we just install the certifciates in the windows store.

Now we want a behaviour like the "windows remote desktop". Once the we connect to the device we get the (self signed) certificate. Then we ask the user if he trust the certificate. This is quite easy with `SslStream`.

Initialize SSL stream:

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
```

Handler:

```
static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        string certificateHash = CreateHash(certificate);

        //pseudo code -> go to database and check if the certificate is already trusted
        if(database.TrustedCertificates.Contains(certificateHash))
        {
            return true;
        }

        //TODO ask for permission 
        bool isTrusted = true;
        if (isTrusted)
        {
            //TODO add certificate (hash) to store
            database.TrustedCertificates.Add(certificateHash);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

We do not want to add the manually trusted certificates in the windows built in store. Instead we would have our very own certificate store in our database. Therefor the trusted certificate would only be valid for our application.

Now I'm wondering if it's best practice to store the trusted certificates in a own store rather than to add them to the windows certificate store (certlm.msc). Is it save enough to store them in the app's database (just make a table TrustedCertificates)? Do the certificates need to be hashed like passwords? Should this be avoided in any case and only use the windows certificate store?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Certificate can be added to Local Machine store without possibility to export it back, this is secure. Not sure what do you mean by hashing certificate... are you sure you meant really hashing (one way transformation)?

Comment: @Alexey the question is regarding if we DO NOT store them in the local machine store, but store the trusted certificates in our own database. I'll update the sample. Regarding the hashing: if trusted certificates are stored in db, it's maybe more secure to store the hashed instead of plain text (or .cer files)?

Comment: Hashing is one way, i.e you can not get the original text back. Normally hashing used to ensure the data integrity not security.

Comment: will edit again to make clear where hashing takes place.... however using hashing or not seems to be a "side-question". Storing the certificates not in the windows certificate store just seems wrong to me. That's why I ask "how do you store your (self signed) certificates?" if you can't install them?

Comment: @Thangadurai hopefully your passwords are hashed and not encrypted...https://haveibeenpwned.com/ ;-P

Comment: As long as private key of your cert is protected, cert can be stored anywhere. Now with windows cert store feature of securing private key (like password protection, grant access to private key to only limited users, marking private key non exportable etc.) comes inbuilt. So if I were you, I would not have reinvented wheel.

Comment: @PankajKapare aggreed for server side certificates. But how to handle this on client-side? For example: each web browsers has it's own "private" certificate store. https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1059377